# Case insensitive search in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, frameworks

I am developing grails application which uses file searching.For that I wrote the following code. This code works and it is gives the results with case sensitive.But I want to search files without case sensitive.

```
def criteria = FileDomain.createCriteria()
 def results = criteria {
    and {
      like('user', User.findById(session?.user))
      or {
        like('filename', '%' + params.fileSearchKey + '%')
        like('referenceFilename', '%' + params.fileSearchKey + '%')
         }
       }
    }
```

Can anyone provide help on this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe using

```
ilike('filename', "%${params.fileSearchKey}%")
ilike('referenceFilename', "%${params.fileSearchKey}%")
```

is the way you are meant to do [case insensitive](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.x/guide/GORM.html#finders) searches

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this in Grails 2.x is by using [the eq node](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html):

```
eq("branch", "london", [ignoreCase: true])
```

Comment: Strange...I'm getting groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: eq() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap)

This is in Grails 2.5.0.  Without the map at the end, it works fine.